# Cordova Camera Plugin JSON.stringify()ing error - Ionic project on iOS

Tags: ios, json, cordova, cordova-plugins, ionic2

The cordova camera plugin is not working with my ionic 2 beta 10 project in iOS/running on my iPhone.

I get this JSON.stringify()ing error and other errors below when I press the button that initiates the camera.

I didn't have an issue with this with ionic 2 beta 9.

I removed and readded the plugin in terminal and rebuilt the app for iOS many times, with no luck.

[image]

Here is my camera destination type:

[image]

Comment: Could you please edit the OP and add the part of the code where you're setting the `Camera.DestinationType`?

Comment: hi @sebaferreras just added the camera destination type to the post, thanks.